# Goodbye and godspeed, Keen - and thank you for playing a large part in making this site great

Tags: discussion, moderation, users

For those who aren't aware, Keen has [stepped down as moderator and left SF&F](http://stackexchange.com/users/375283/keen?tab=accounts).  **It is up to him to decide whether he wants to share his reasons for leaving, or comment on his departure in any way**, but I think we owe him a fond farewell - as well as an enormous debt of gratitude for everything he has done for us [in the FOUR YEARS he was a mod](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election/1) (to say nothing of his earlier stint as a regular user here).

**Thank you, Keen, goodbye, and godspeed.  We wish you weren't leaving, but we're glad you let us get to know you, and we are all grateful for all your hard work on the behalf of this community.**

[*Go raibh maith agat, agus slán go fóill!*](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&newwindow=1&q=go%20raibh%20maith%20agat%20agus%20sl%C3%A1n%20go%20f%C3%B3ill%20translate&oq=Go%20raibh%20maith%20agat%2C%20agus%20sl%C3%A1n%20go%20f%C3%B3ill%21%20tran&gs_l=serp.3.0.33i21.5158.7019.0.8795.5.5.0.0.0.0.218.654.0j3j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.3.435.1iaa9t-rU6A)

Comment: I’m curious, since I’ve never noticed Keen very much (just seen the name around). Is he of the Gaelic persuasion, since you gave the parting cheers in Irish?

Comment: Ah, I see. I asked because I am in complete and utter agreement with you—Irish has been my favourite language since I was about 14 or 15, and it’s quite rare to see snippets of it on SE (especially here!), so it almost made me fangirl a little. :-D

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[image]

Keen has worked tirelessly to make this community a better place, doing so with grace, patience, and calm.

Thanks for all the hard work, Keen.  I'm sure I speak for many when I say that you will be sorely missed.

Comment: Hear, hear! You have been a SFF mod from the time I joined SE and found the site. I especially appreciate your willingness to stand up for women and women's issues -- as one of the few (comparatively) women on the site, it meant a lot to me. Thank you :)

Comment: I generally tend to lurk on SFF, but I must say that I've seen Keen on practically every encounter I've had here. The sheer number of posts I stumble across with Keen either asking, editing, commenting or answering  is staggering. Goodbye Keen, Godspeed and the best of luck with your future endeavours.

Answer (score 17):

You will be missed, Keen.

## Live long and prosper, and may the Force be with you.

Answer (score 6):

Keen: Though we recently didn't see eye to eye, you did perform your duties... dutifully. And you contributed to chat in a manner which I appreciated.  Thank you for your work and your contributions.